# set label in another formusing invoke vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i looking for how to set label in another class using invoke
this is my code in form1.vb

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6969)
        listener.Start()
        listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), listener)

        'Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        'bacaini()
        'connectdatabase()
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog("formload", ex.Message, ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Delegate Sub _cUpdate(ByVal str As String, ByVal lable As Label)

Sub UpdateList(ByVal str As String, ByVal lable As Label)
    Try
        If lable.InvokeRequired Then
            lable.Invoke(New _cUpdate(AddressOf UpdateList), str, lable)
        Else

            lable.Text = str
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'errorLog("updatelist", ex.Message, ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
Sub MessageReceived(ByVal str As String)
   UpdateList("this work", label1)
End Sub
```

and i want change set label1 in form2.vb, but it didn't work can anyone help me

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: no error but i can't set label in another form

Comment: So the application compiles and build? Is `label1` referenced correctly. Should it not be, form2.label1? or what ever you have named your form2 instance.

Comment: i try with this but it didn't work

Sub MessageReceived(ByVal str As String)
   UpdateList("this work", form2.label1)
End Sub